# Configure .NET CORE MVC App with Authorization roles (2 SqlLite DB's)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I learned about AuthRoles in a .Net Framework MVC App ([Here](https://github.com/DLGEJ-Entornos/Astrofilm) project) working with 2 SqlServer databases (1 for Roles, Users and Passwords...) and the other for the App tables.

Now I'm trying the same in NET CORE with SqlLite, but I don't know how to manage 2 DbContext. How to make migrations to my App DB and let the Roles DB only working for Authentication, Register, etc.

First at all, I follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial to get in touch with net core and I finished a mvc sample(1 table, no foreign keys). But I hadn't Authentication logic and only the App db.

After that I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-owner-manager-and-administrator-authorization-handlers) tutorial that works with Roles SqlLite DB **but only has 1 DB**.(finished sample [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/security/authorization/secure-data/samples/final3)).

Could you explain to me **how can I work with authentications in .net core** and if it's possible, use 2 bd, 1 for the app and the other for user passwords, roles, etc?

#### EDIT

Trying with my net Core mvc app, I managed to create a Identity sqlLite.db. and I created from migration another db (App tables), which by now only has user table. But some issues:

- The aplication of migration (using --context 'AppDbContext') generates a db with Identity tables that are already generated in the IdentityRolesUsers db, mixed with my app table User.
- When registering an user, the AspUsers table (IdentityDb) aren't linked to Users table and the AspUser is created in the IdentityDb.

[Here](https://github.com/JorgeDLG/ClaveSol/tree/reset/Migrations) my migrations files(before ef update). Any solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, you can use **multiple DbContext** in one project for one database or multiple databases. It is simple and straightforward; you should register each DbContext in **ConfigureServise separately**.

But why you want to separate your 'role Database'?

In the link below, you can learn how to work with Identity in Dotnet core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The separation of role db I think it's a common practice. When you create a project with authentication:

    dotnet new webapp --auth Individual -o WebApp1

It's creates a app.db (sqlslite) with roles, users, passwords,etc. And the goal is to link that with the App db user tables. (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1#tie-the-contact-data-to-the-user).).

Comment: It depends on your **solution architecture**, but in default structure in .net project, you can see your AppDbContext inherit from IdentityDbContext. It means you have one database for everything.

Comment: [Here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2144293.aspx?Best+practice+to+create+Asp+Net+Core+project+with+database+first+and+Individual+identity) DA924, defends keep Users Identity info in one Identity DB, and another DB for the App. My teacher, teach us this practice developing with mvc asp.net framework([here](https://github.com/DLGEJ-Entornos/Astrofilm)), I don't know if is a obsolete practice and with .net core is better save all in one unique db.

In case I wanted to do it like this. In .net core , how can I do it?